# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x48) - broken with iOS13.1 (dev build 2)

Tags: iphone, ios13, swift5

So, I updated my iPhone 6S to the second dev build of iOS13.1 yesterday and all of the sudden my app (which is on the app store with 0 crashes showing on the Connect app) doesn't work when run on my device. It **does** however work in Xcode's simulators. I'm using Xcode 10.3, but the Xcode 11 beta does the same thing, the simulators work on the beta too (though they break my app in other ways).

When I tap on a button, which is supposed to bring me to the detail view of the button tapped I'm getting this error:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x48)
```

Which is on this code

```
// sets up the audio for use in the app --------------------------------------------------------------//
        let GetReady = Bundle.main.path(forResource: “Get_Ready_up9db”, ofType: “m4a”)
        // this tells the compiler what to do when action is received
        do {
            audioPlayer_GetReady = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: GetReady! )) // Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x48)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category(rawValue: convertFromAVAudioSessionCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.ambient)))
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        }
        catch{
            print(error)
        }
```

I have no idea why it's doing this all of the sudden, but because I can't figure it out I'm a bit scared as I'm sure iOS 13 is coming out very, very soon.

Please help!

Comment: Xcode provides a powerful debugger. You are encouraged to use it. And – not related to the issue – there is `url(forResource:withExtension:)` in `Bundle` to avoid the extra step to create the URL.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not really a dev. I'm a UX designer that can't afford a real dev so, I try to do it myself. That's all to explain that I can't figure out how to use the debugger controls in Xcode beyond setting the blue flag and then stepping and what not until the error occurs. How I figure out how to fix it or what all that actually tells me after that eludes me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have initiated your "audioPlayer_GetReady" in it's declaration like this:

```
var audioPlayer_GetReady = AVAudioPlayer()
```

Try to restructure to only declare it's type:

```
var audioPlayer_GetReady: AVAudioPlayer
```

You now need to initialize it in the init-method of your class or, if you are sure that it will be initialize elsewhere before any reference to it, declare it with exclamation:

```
var audioPlayer_GetReady: AVAudioPlayer!
```

Comment: yes, that is how I had it, but when I change it to your suggestions I get these errors: Class level error "Class 'BoxingReadyViewController' has no initializers" and then on the vars "1. Stored property 'audioPlayer_Bell' without initial value prevents synthesized initializers"

Comment: Thank you @user1755137, this answer solved this issue for me: restructuring declaration to declare only the type + instantiating into the init method instead of instantiating it later.

Comment: Sadly I can't get any of your suggestions to work. I've updated to the latest iOS 13.1 db 3 (released 9/10/19) and the GA for Xcode 11 and it still works for the Xcode sims, but not on my actual iPhone 6S (iOS 13.1 db3). If I change the vars to ":AVAudioPlayer" instead of "= AVAudioPlayer()" I get an error on the class "Class 'BoxingReadyViewController" has no initializers" that's still an error after updating my inits with either one of your suggestions. the first suggestion error: "Cannot invoke 'path' with no arguments' Opt2 has no errors, but the Class still has that no inits error :(

Comment: Try to add an init method to your class instead of directly initiating your properties.

Comment: I figured it out. Your initial answer was 99% right... "var audioPlayer_GetReady: AVAudioPlayer". The 1% is to add an exclamation mark at the end "var audioPlayer_GetReady: AVAudioPlayer!" The simple addition of the "!" fixed it all. Stupid, stupid Xcode and how they ALMOST automatically migrate code from previous swift version to apple's newest. It's always ALMOST good, but then it's not. Now I have to figure out why my SystemDefaults aren't updating the screen after they're saved. Thank you for your assistance @user1755137

Comment: add the "!" at the end of your "var audioPlayer_GetReady: AVAudioPlayer" answer and then yes :)

Comment: sorry, I forgot to get back to this to check the ! was added. apologies, thanks for your help.